# CSS: Skewed button using pseudo position: absolute

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position

I have a button with only a single tag (`<a>`). I want to skew the background of the button and keep the text as is, so I'm using [this code](https://codepen.io/irishrunnergriffin/pen/JjMMYPK), which is working as expected in my Codepen example:

```
<a class="et_pb_button et_pb_pricing_table_button" href="#">$200 / Month</a>
```

```
.et_pb_pricing_table_button {
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px 60px;
    position: relative;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.et_pb_pricing_table_button:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: skewX(-15deg);
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #ffd100;
}
.et_pb_pricing_table_button:hover:after{
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

However, when I apply that code to [my page](https://nerunsdev.wpengine.com/), it is not rendering as expected (not visible). I can't find anything that is stopping this from working (the parent elements are position: relative). I also tried increasing the z-index of the pseudo selectors, but that didn't help either. What am I missing?

Comment: Negative z-index values LOWER the visibility, try a higher value, plz make a snippet we can run here

Comment: @ZachJensz Yes, I had tried increasing the z-index (using a higher value, e.g. 999) but that did not have any effect.

Comment: You're hiding it in your css with `!important`.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I see this rule in the theme, but even after disabling it in Chrome dev tools, the background that is added via the psuedo selector still is not showing up: 
`body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_pricing_tables_0 .et_pb_pricing_table_button.et_pb_button:after`

Comment: Could be that you're trying to position this background layer between the text and the background of parent elements.  It would be easier to debug without the pseudo-element, so I'd create a real element on your page for debugging and get the styles looking right first.

Comment: For an example, see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/JasonGoemaat/pen/VwyQarY).   With z-index of -1, the background only appears only when not hidden by the other background.   With 10 it displays over the text.